# Python - how to build a function that has the option "inplace"

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

How should I build a function from scratch that has the option `inplace` like the one in `pd.rename(inplace=True)`?

imaging something like this:

```
def my_func(df=, inplace=):
    some_code_that_process_df
    if inplace == False:
        return df
    else:
        # what should I code in here?
```

Comment: Seems dangerous to allow in-place processing on an arg that can have a default value...

Comment: `inplace` implies the function (although usually it is a method) mutates the object. So mutate the object instead of creating a new object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making a copy or operating on the original dataframe.  You could add some assurance that the original dataframe made it all the way through processing by comparing the object id like so:

```
def my_func(df, inplace=False):

    df_id = id(df)

    if not inplace:
        df = df.copy(deep=True)

    # example processing:
    df.rename(columns={col:col+"_new" for col in df.columns}, inplace=True)

    if inplace and (id(df) != df_id):
        raise ValueError("original dataframe has been lost")
    
    # usually only copies return the df, but I'll leave it for an example
    return df
```

Here's an example where we show the id is the same/changed.  Note if we had done `df = df.rename(...)` the function would fail, since subsequent processing would not be carried out on the original dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,2,3]))

df2 = my_func(df, inplace=True)
df3 = my_func(df, inplace=False)

print(df is df2) # True
print(df is df3) # False
```